# For what value of $c$ is $f$ a probability density function?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, density-function

Consider the function $f(x)$ defined as $f(x)=ce^{-x^4},\; x\in \mathbb{R}$. For what value of $c$ is $f$ a p.d.f?

> Solution: Using the p.d.f conditions:

$c\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^4}dx=1$

Set $x^4=u$ then, $dx=\frac{u^{-3/4}}{4} $. So, integration now changes to:
$$\frac{c}{4}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}{u^{-3/4}}du=1 \implies\frac{c}{4}\Gamma(1/4)=1 \implies c=\frac{4}{\Gamma(1/4)}$$.

But the answer given is : $c=\frac{2}{\Gamma(1/4)}$. What have I done wrong here?

Comment: The mistake is that $x^4$ is not injective over $\mathbb R$, but only over $[0,\infty[$ (or $]-\infty,0]$.) So correct is $$c\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^4}\,\mathrm dx=2c\int_0^\infty e^{-x^4}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{2c}4\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-u}}{u^\frac34}\,\mathrm du.$$

Now set this equal to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since $x$ changes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, then $u=x^4$ changes from $0$ to $\infty$ **twice** (once because $x$ changes from $0$ to $\infty$ and the other time because $x$ changes from $-\infty$ to $0$). Hence you must first write $$2c\int_0^\infty e^{-x^4}dx=1$$then $$\frac{c}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}{u^{-3/4}}du=1$$and continue.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that it must be

$$c\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-{x^4}}dx=2c\int_0^\infty e^{-{x^4}}dx$$

and now you do your substitution, otherwise that substitution is illegal as the function is then not injective...